# Showing a sequence converges in $l^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to show that the sequence $x^{(n)} \in l^2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $x_k^{(n)}= \frac{1}{n+k}$, where  $x_k^{(n)}$ is the $k$-th element of the sequence $x^{(n)}$ converges to the zero sequence in $l^2(\mathbb{R})$.

My method involved trying to show that $||x^{(n)}-0||_{l^2}^2 \rightarrow 0$, i.e. that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$ converges to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and looking for some sort of constant $M$ (such as $M = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ as we know this is finite) where $||x^{(n)}-0||_{l^2}^2 \leq \frac{1}{n}M$, for example, in order to apply the sandwich theorem. However I have had no luck so far, any tips for how to manipulate this series would be useful!

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$ is a tail of the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you so much - I think I might have got it: can I write $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} -  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ which tends to 0 as the second sum converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?